# Protobuf generated c++ files are faulty when using imports in .proto

Tags: protocol-buffers

When I generate c++ output files using protoc  with only one "main" proto file without any imports, similar to the protobuf examples everything is generated fine and works when using it in my project.

But when I work with any form of imports, c++ output code is faulty. I compile my .proto with:

```
protoc --cpp_out=../grpc --grpc_out=../grpc --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=/usr/local/bin/grpc_cpp_plugin sample.proto
```

This is my sample code that works:

```
syntax = "proto3";

service SampleService
{
  rpc Login(LoginRequest) returns (LoginResponse) {};
}

message LoginRequest {}

message LoginResponse {}
```

When I try to outsource a single message, **protoc still compiles without errors but is generating faulty cc and h files**.
E.g. adding
import "messages.proto
with content

```
syntax = "proto3";

message LoginRequest
{
}
```

My c++ code wont compile anymore and contains faulty stuff.
My sample.pb.h contains and unresolved inclusion

```
#include "messages.pb.h
```

And my sample.pb.cc contains two unresolved functions

```
::protobuf_messages_2eproto::InitDefaults();
::protobuf_messages_2eproto::AddDescripttors();
```

**Edit:**
It seems I have to compile each .proto I already import too. But then I'm confused.

I want to have a "main" .proto which includes a service.proto and a messages.proto which contains imports to all my messages, which are also .proto-files . From time to time I want to create new messages so I can include them easily instead of one big unreadable file.

How do i do this? I don't want to have 200 output cc/h files for my little project. How is that intended?

My folder structure:

```
*src-Folder*
--main.proto (imports service.proto and messages.proto)
--service.proto (imports messages.proto)
--messages.proto (imports /messages/*
--*messages-Folder*
-----messagepair1
-----messagepair2
...
```

**Edit2:**
I wrote myself a workarround until there is a better solution against that file cluttering. I edited my .proto files and removed every description then the messages itself (imports, syntax, package...) use "cat" to concatenate each .proto file into one single file and compile this with protoc as posted above. 
Not nice but I dont want 50-100 cc/h files later in my project. **There have to be a better resolution.**

Comment: Yes, normally you end up with one .pb.h and one .pb.cc file per .proto file. If that's creating clutter then I would recommend just consolidating your messages into fewer .proto files. Another thing that might help is to have your build system run protoc automatically; the generated files will have to be stored somewhere but at least they won't need to be checked in to version control that way.